# Talend tSystem component is not running batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, talend

I am attempting to run a batch file using the tSystem component on Talend.

Batch File Path in tSystem Command section: `C:\\Users\\Account\\Documents\\Batch.bat`

The batch file runs correctly in the command prompt when run outside of Talend, but when plugged into the tSystem Talend component, it just prints the contents of the batch file instead of running.

Ex.

```
Batch file text here
Press any key to continue...
```

This component works fine on a different machine, is there a setting that needs to be adjusted?

Answer (score 0):

To launch the Windows batch file with `tSystem`, you need to do it through `cmd.exe` by passing an array of parameters where the last one is the actual batch file to launch.

[image]

Note : You may need to specify a current directory (the "home" directory) depending how the BAT file is designed.